# No HockeyApp crash reports when using Firebase and HockeyApp simultaneously

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, hockeyapp

In our iOS app we use the HockeyApp SDK and Firebase SDK.

We initialize both in AppDelegate directly at startup:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  

    BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().configureWithIdentifier(hockeyAppId);
    BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().startManager();
    BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().authenticator.authenticateInstallation();

    FIRApp.configure()

    [...]
}
```

The problem is that when we don´t activate Firebase our crash reports are correctly sent to HockeyApp and everything works fine. But when we activate Firebase then nothing happens when it comes to crash reports on the HockeyApp side.

Why is this happening? Is it possible that Firebase prevents HockeyApp from sending crash reports? And how is it possible to maybe solve this problem?

Info: I am aware that HockeyApp does not send crash reports with an attached debugger.

Thanks very much for reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's technically not possible to use more than one third-party crash reporting tool at the same time in one app.
iOS allows only for one exception handler to be registered at a time, so if you initialize Firebase after the HockeyApp SDK, the Firebase exception handler replaces HockeyApp's or vice versa.
You need to pick one of the SDKs to handle crash reports and disable the crash reporting functionality in the other.